# Caching function results including maybe void

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, template-meta-programming

I have a template whose template parameter represents a functional. That functional is called within the template, and the result of the functional should be stored, like this:

```
template <class F>
class C {
   F f;
   /* type see below */ cached;

   // ... somewhere ...
       cached = f();
};
```

I would like to retrieve the stored value later. Now, the template is supposed to work even if `f` returns `void`. Since I cannot generate variables of type `void`, the cached value should be of a `void_placeholder_t` type. Hence my class should look as follows:

```
template <class F>
class C {
   F f;
   result_after_void_replacement_t<F()> cached;

   // ... somewhere ...
       cached = invoke_and_replace_void (f);
};
```

Now I worked the whole afternoon on this problem and came up with the below solution. Honestly, I doubt that this problem is uncommon -- so isn't there a standard solution?

[Sorry, lengthy. Example given at the end.]

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <functional>

struct void_placeholder_t {};

// dummy type, since we do not want to overload comma for void_placeholder_t
struct void_replacer { };

// overload comma to return either t oder void_replacer {}
// (uses that if first argument is void, overload is not called)
template <class T>
constexpr decltype(auto) operator , (T && t, void_replacer) {
    return std::forward<T> (t);
}

//
// replace_void
// helper transforming a void_replacer into a void_placeholder_t
template <class T>
constexpr decltype(auto) replace_void (T && t) {
    return std::forward<T> (t);
}

constexpr void_placeholder_t replace_void (void_replacer) {
    return void_placeholder_t {};
}

//
// remove_rvalue_reference
//
template<class T> struct remove_rvalue_reference { using type = T; };
template<class T> struct remove_rvalue_reference<T &&> { using type = T; };
template <class T> using remove_rvalue_reference_t
    = typename remove_rvalue_reference<T>::type;

//
// result_after_void_replacement, result_after_void_replacement_t
//
template <class S> struct result_after_void_replacement;
template <class F, class ... Args>
struct result_after_void_replacement <F (Args ...)> {
    using type
        = remove_rvalue_reference_t < decltype (
            replace_void(
            ( std::declval<F> () (std::declval<Args> () ...),
            void_replacer {} ) )
        ) >;
};

template <class S>
using result_after_void_replacement_t = typename 
    result_after_void_replacement<S>::type;

//
// invoke_and_replace_void
//
template <class F, class ... Args>
constexpr result_after_void_replacement_t<F && (Args &&...)>
invoke_and_replace_void (F && f, Args && ... args)
{
    return replace_void(
    ( std::forward<F> (f) (std::forward<Args> (args) ...),
    void_replacer {} ) );
}

// example

void f(double) { }
double g(double d) { return d + 11.0; }

int main() {
    // conversion, without invoke_and_replace_void
    auto xf = replace_void ( (f(42.0), void_replacer {}) );
    std::cout << typeid(xf).name () << std::endl;
    auto xg = replace_void ( (g(42.0), void_replacer {}) );
    std::cout << typeid(xg).name () << " " << xg << std::endl;

    // conversion, with invoke_and_replace_void and no type deduction
    using F = void (double);
    result_after_void_replacement_t<F& (double)> zf = 
        invoke_and_replace_void (f, 42.0);
    std::cout << typeid(zf).name () << std::endl;

    using G = double (double);
    result_after_void_replacement_t<G& (double)> zg = 
        invoke_and_replace_void (g, 42.0);
    std::cout << typeid(zg).name () << " " << zg << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The common way is to create specialization of class `C` (or some part of it) for `void` type, that will not store return value.

Comment: Hm, indeed, maybe that's easier.

Comment: A potentially hackier approach: `typedef std::conditional_t<std::is_void<decltype(F())>::value, int, decltype(F())> cached_type;` and `cached_type f;`. If `F` returns void `f` will just be a junk `int` variable.

Comment: Is `f` supposed to be called only once?

Comment: Yes, we can assume that.

Comment: If it's not performance-critical, you might be able to use `async` with `std::launch::deferred`, and store a `std::shared_future<std::result_of_t<F()>>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no *standard* solution as in "something which is in the C++ standard". There was an attempt to support ["Regular Void"](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2015/p0146r0.html) which wasn't favored by the Evolution Working Group at the October 2015 meeting.

The *usual* approach is to deal with situations where function object *may* return `void` and the value would be processed using specialization. Especially when the function template in question is relatively complex and the common parts can't be factored easily, this approach is unfortunately rather annoying.

Comment: I put an improved version on Bitbucket: https://bitbucket.org/johannes_gerd_becker/voidunit . In case anybody needs it.

Answer (score 3):

This should work for your case

```
template <class F, bool>
class C_helper{
public:
   F f;
   /* type see below */ cached;

   // ... somewhere ...
       cached = f();
};
template <class F>
class C_helper<F, true> {
public:
   F f;

   // ... somewhere ...
       f();
};

template <class F>
class C: public C_helper<F, std::is_void<std::result_of<F()>>::value> {
};
```

Answer (score 1):

This works fine:

```
template <typename Fn, typename RET, typename... Args >
struct Cache
{
    Cache( Fn f ) : _fn(f) {}
    const RET& operator()(Args ...args)
    {
        _cache = _fn( std::forward<Args>( args ) ... );
        return _cache;
    }
    Fn _fn;
    RET _cache;
};

template <typename Fn, typename... Args >
struct Cache< Fn, void, Args...>
{
    Cache( Fn f ) : _fn(f) {}
    void operator()(Args ...args)
    {
        _fn( std::forward<Args>( args ) ... );
    }
    Fn _fn;
};

template <typename Fn, typename... Args >
using C = Cache< Fn, typename std::result_of< Fn( Args... ) >::type, Args... >;

void f(double) { }
double g(double d) { return d + 11.0; }


C<decltype(&g), double> cache_g(g);
double res = cache_g( 1.0 );

C<decltype(&f), double> cache_f(f);
cache_f( 2.0 );
```